# Is there a way to see if any column is modified by a trigger in a SQL Db?

Tags: sql, database, triggers

Is there a way to query the Db to see what triggers are interacting with dbo.Table1.FooColumn in the DataBase I am working on? I need to investigate what triggers are possibly modifying "FooColumn" column on Table1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL, Postgres, or SQL Server, you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS`:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND (EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE = 'Table1' OR LCASE(ACTION_STATEMENT) LIKE '%table1%')
AND LCASE(ACTION_STATEMENT) LIKE '%foocolumn%';
```

Oracle doesn't support the ANSI INFORMATION_SCHEMA, so you could instead use:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_TRIGGERS
WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' OR LCASE(TRIGGER_BODY) LIKE '%table1%')
AND LCASE(TRIGGER_BODY) LIKE '%foocolumn%';
```

The above queries look for triggers defined for `Table1` and affect `FooColumn` or triggers that are defined for another table but affect `Table1.FooColumn`.

Note that if the DBMS supports triggers that can call stored procedures (like Oracle), you'll have to manually inspect all the stored procedures called by a trigger.